# Any way of resizing UIImageView / Label Text Size based on iOS Device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am learning to use constraints in Interface Builder and have tried messing around with aspect ratio and width/height properties of UIImageViews. I was just curious if there was anyway to autoresize, sort of like "zoom" to prevent a lot of white space in bigger iPhones? (6 & 6Plus).

Example of what I mean:

[image]
Notice the bigger devices have a lot of white space, would be nice to simply resize that UIImageView up top along with label based on device,  sort of like I did with that bottom button by using aspect ratio. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried using constraints to set the items distance from its superviews? For example set the Login buttons leading edge distance from superviews leading edge to ~20 instead of setting a width constraint on the button?

Comment: This is precisely what auto-layout constraints are for. Simply add a leading and trailing space constraint to the image view and it will scale perfectly for any screen size. You will also need to add the appropriate constraints for the y position and height as well.

Comment: That seemed to work great as far as scaling my images thanks. How would I go about doing this for label text sizes? Also I notice that my code in viewWillAppear now doesn't work properly in turning the larger two images (6&6Plus) into perfect circles: eaturedAdPhoto.layer.cornerRadius = featuredAdPhoto.frame.size.height / 2;
    featuredAdPhoto.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    featuredAdPhoto.layer.borderWidth = 0;

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

With IOS 8 apple introduced size classes as an addition to auto layout. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

With size classes you can have different user interfaces for different devices and different device orientations.

For The case you are describing (dynamically resizing of Views), you can also just go with the "old" basic auto layout functionality:

1. Set Constraints of UIImageView to keep a fixed distance to the top
   Layout guide
2. Set Constraint UIImageView to keep a fixed distance to your top UITExtField
3. Center UIImageView in Container
4. Set Fixed aspect Ratio of your Image

Tadaaa, you have an dynamically resizing Image that will always keep its aspect ration.